# Wizard Control C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет :)

Начала основывать Wizard Control в WinForms и возник вопрос, как возможно с помощью выбора одной из radio button при нажатии next открывалось определенное окно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете уточнить, какой именно контрол вы используете?
Это самописный контрол или какой-то готовый, который вы скачали/подключили и используете?
Просто, стандартного контрола нет, на сколько я знаю, есть от сторонних производителей.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov готовые AdvancedWizard и AeroWizard, но по целям, я думаю, мне больше подходит первое

Comment: Тот же AdvancedWizard, он доступен же, https://github.com/SteveBate/AdvancedWizard . Просто посмотрите, как он устроен внутри, пройдите по примерам в режиме отладки.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Я хотела чтоб открывались разные окна в зависимоти от моего выбора